# Getting an exception Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class while trying to send the email using GMAIL API

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

Written in Async task - on background

```
public MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String bodyText) throws MessagingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(bodyText);
        return email;
    }
```

Error:
Getting error like this when I tried to call create email method in the async background.
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class

> java.lang.Class
>           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
>                               at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent(MimeMessage.java:1516)
>                               at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:1176)
>                               at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1555)
>                               at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1539)

Comment: Did you follow the [JavaMail for Android instructions](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android)?

Comment: Thanks.. by adding those instructions and by removing
implemention 'group : sunmail, name:javamail, version:1.5.5'
Code was working fine.